# Using Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt native 64 bit to install openssl and getting error

Tags: visual-studio, path, openssl, 64-bit

When I use the developer command prompt for the native 64 bit of my computer to attempt to install openssl I get the error message LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'.  When I check the path variable for the x64 developer command prompt all of locations for visual studio are x86.  I'm not sure if that somehow got messed up or what it's supposed to be and googling for the past 5 hours was unhelpful.